# Windows + SetCommState how to set RTS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-7, mfc, serial-port

I have an application that has been ported up from VC++ 6 where it worked fine.  The code in question uses the WinAPI for a serial device driver.  When ported to VS2012, the same code behaves rather differently.

Create a DCB, set SetCommState and go.  CTS was set high, RTS was set high and you were on your way.

Since ported up to VS2012 Pro MFC, I am finding that it sets up SetCommState the same with or without hardware flow control:

```
memset(&dcb, 0x00, sizeof(dcb));
dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);

// Must be TRUE, only binary mode in Windows
dcb.fBinary = TRUE;
dcb.fParity = FALSE;

// XOn/XOff disabled
dcb.fTXContinueOnXoff = TRUE;
dcb.fOutX = FALSE;
dcb.fInX = FALSE;
dcb.XonLim = 0;
dcb.XoffLim = 0;
dcb.XonChar = 0;
dcb.XoffChar = 0;

// Misc Stuff
dcb.EofChar = 0;
dcb.EvtChar = 0;
dcb.ErrorChar = 0;
dcb.fErrorChar = FALSE;
dcb.fNull = FALSE;
dcb.fAbortOnError = FALSE;

// 8N1 Setup
dcb.ByteSize = 8;
dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;

// Baud Rate
if (dwBaudRate == BAUD_115200)
{
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_115200;
}
else
{
    dcb.BaudRate = CBR_38400;
}

// setup hardware flow control
if (bHardware == eYesHardwareFlowControl)
{
    // ================ FLOW CONTROL ON ================
    switch (bIgnoreCTS)
    {
        case eIgnoreCTS:
            dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
            break;

        case eEnableCTS:
            dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = TRUE;
            break;

        default:
        case eCTSDecideLater:
            dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = TRUE;
            break;
    }

    // DSR Flow Control
    dcb.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;
    dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;

    // <<Hardware flow control On(TRUE) Off(FALSE)>>
    dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;

    // <<Hardware flow control On(_HANDSHAKE) Off(_ENBLE)>>
    dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_HANDSHAKE;
}
else
{
    // ================ FLOW CONTROL OFF ================
    switch (bIgnoreCTS)
    {
        case eIgnoreCTS:
            dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
            break;

        case eEnableCTS:
            dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = TRUE;
            break;

        default:
        case eCTSDecideLater:
            dcb.fOutxCtsFlow = FALSE;
            break;
    }

    // DSR Flow Control
    dcb.fDsrSensitivity = FALSE;
    dcb.fOutxDsrFlow = FALSE;

    dcb.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
    dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE;
}

if (SetCommState(m_hIdComDev, &dcb) == WINDOWS_API_ZERO_IS_BAD)
{
    dwLastError = GetLastError();
}
```

At this point, I have set up the DCB, cleared it.  I don't read in the previous state is I don't want to trust any garbage of anyone that previously used the port. Then I set up every field with Baud, Flow Control and CTS Ignore being the only optional items.

So, what I've noticed is that I can create situation where the Device and the PC don't communicate.  Now, mind you, they always did before and they always work with Hyperterminal, ProComm, TeraTerm and so on.  What I can see is that when these comm programs start (and the old VC++ 6 App), when the device is created and set up, RTS is immediately set high.

Now, my App, once the DCB is set up, SetCommState called; RTS is always LOW.  And when this happens, communications is toast.

I want to FORCE RTS to be high and thought I could do it like this:

```
if (EscapeCommFunction(m_hIdComDev, CLRRTS) == WINDOWS_API_ZERO_IS_BAD)
{
    dwLastError = GetLastError();
}

if (EscapeCommFunction(m_hIdComDev, SETRTS) == WINDOWS_API_ZERO_IS_BAD)
{
    dwLastError = GetLastError();
}
```

But this fails, it gives an error 87 (parameter error).  And I cannot quite figure it out.  Even if I just SETRTS high only, it fails.

Any ideas on how I can force Windows to set RTS high after I setup the comm parameters in the DCB?

Comment: Error 87 occurs when trying to manually set RTS while handshaking or Toggle is set for RTS in DCB.  Stupid enough mistake by me.  The other items by Hans are taken care of.  So that leaves ... Why is WinAPI driving RTS low no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

Well it turned out to be a device problem and not a windows problem at all.